# Django admin panel: How to show models with ManyToMany and OneToMany relationship within another model?

Tags: django, django-admin

I tried so hard to write a question title that could somewhat point to the problem, but couldn't. So here is the question in details:

I have a `Product` model, a `Usage` model and a `SubUsage` model. `Usage` model has a OneToMAny relationship with `SubUsage` model, where for every usage there may be various sub_usages, and the `Product` model has ManyToMany relationship with these two models, in which a product may have different usages and sub_usages.

These models are as below:

```
class Usage(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    usage_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
    )


class SubUsage(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    sub_usage_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
    )
    usage = models.ForeignKey(
        Usage,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )


class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    product_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
    )
    usage = models.ManyToManyField(Usage)
    sub_usage = models.ManyToManyField(SubUsage)
```

Now in the admin panel, I have product form, in which I can choose usages and sub_usages; as the image below:

[image]

The problem is that, each usage has different sub_usages, which may has the same name as another sub_usage of another usage; I want to be able to know that each item in sub_usages list is related to which usage, so that if a product has only usage1 and usage2, then the admin won't mistakenly select a sub_usage from usage3 which has the same name as a sub_usage from usage2.

Comment: If you just want to inform the user, which sub_usage is belong to a specific usage, why you do not modify the `str()` method of the `SubUsage`?

Comment: @AD Ok, that's a good idea actually. :) is it possible to return sub_usage_name and usage name at the same time in sub_usage str method?

Comment: Yes it is possible but probably you need some checks